# the result of parsing JSON on different columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am having trouble using json_normalize, when I apply them to the following python code:

```
json ={ 'id': 146731073,
    'id_str': '146731073',
    'indices': [17, 28],
    'name': 'Chris jeday',
    'screen_name': 'ChrisJeday'}

pd.json_normalize(json,'screen_name')
```

get tokkenized result in multiple rows, wish them in single row

```
    0
0   C
1   h
2   r
3   i
4   s
5   J
6   e
7   d
8   a
9   y
```

I expect something like this:

```
    0
0   ChrisJeday
```

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You can get a Series like this:

```
screen_names = pd.json_normalize(json).screen_name
print(type(screen_names))
print(screen_names)

[Out]:
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
0    ChrisJeday
Name: screen_name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

`.json_normalize()` is good for nested JSON.
You have there a plain dict.
Dicts can be passed as arguments straight to the DataFrame constructor.

So if you want a DataFrame you can simply do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([json],columns=['screen_name'])
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json,index=[0],columns=['screen_name'])
```

Result:

```
  screen_name
0  ChrisJeday
```